# Can we use Rolle's Theorem if $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $(a, b)$ only?

Tags: real-analysis

Why in Rolle's theorem the function is given to be continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$? What if we take open interval for continuity as well? Please answer if anyone knows.

Comment: Then the condition f(a)=f(b) would be empty hence no conclusion could be drawn from the hypothesis.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, given by

$$\begin{cases}
x & 0 \leq x < 1\\
0 & x = 1.
\end{cases}$$

Note that $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $(0, 1)$, and $f(0) = f(1)$, but $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$; in particular, there is no $c \in (0, 1)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

As the above example shows, continuity on the open interval only is insufficient for Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: I was typing, got there a little later than you did. Qe thought of the same exact example. Funny!

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, what if we take the closed interval [a,b] for differentiability? Will it create some problem?

Comment: Excellent counterexample there.

Comment: @WaqarAliShah: You would have to first define what it means for a function to be differentiable on $[a, b]$. The problem here is what it means to be differentiable at the endpoints.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, Given the closed interval [a,b], Left-hand derivative at "b" and right -hand derivative at "a" exist. I have also seen some theorems and examples  where the function has been given to be differentiable on the closed interval.

Comment: OK. Note that differentiable on $[a, b]$ implies differentiable on $(a, b)$, so what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem does not hold. For instance, consider the function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

$$    f\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x & \text{if}  \ x \in (0,1) \\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.\\ $$

All of the hypotheses of the theorem hold (except continuity on the extremal points), but $f'(x)=1$ for every $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Of course! Otherwise, it would of course be continuous in the closed interval. Thank you for the remark, I'll fix it immediately.